# How to ask manager to stay for an intership?

Tags: internship

Together with 2 classmates I have an intership at a company A. After this internship we have to look for another internship. I haven't found a company to do my next internship at. And one of my classmates said to me that our manager from the company said to them(my classmates) that if they needed an internship it's possible to do it at company A.

I would like to do my next internship at company A. I'm just not sure how to ask it.

Should I say that I have heard what my manager said and that I would like to stay for the next period?

Or should I ask and act like I haven't heard it before?

/**** edit ****/

So I asked my manager if I could do my next internship at the company. And after 4 days he came to me with a project, so I can do my next internship at that company. Thx for all the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ask as if you had not heard that as your friends probably should not have shared it.  But be prepared that they may not decide to keep you. If they told the others they could come back and not you, that is often an indicator that they think you are the weaker performer. If they do turn you down, talk to the manager about what you can do better in your next internship and fix that at your next company.

Answer (score 3):

Act as if you haven't heard a thing through the grapevine, and simply send an email to your manager stating that you enjoyed working at Company A, and that you'd very much like to stay for another internship. If you don't ask, you don't get. They are not mind readers so it's up to you to tell them what you want from them. The worst thing that happens is that they say "no".

Answer (score 1):

Honesty is always easier to keep track of when possible.

The only question is: is it possible that the conversation they had with your friend was priveliged and intended only for your friend? If so, be prepared for there to possibly be only 1 spot available which may already be taken.

If you think the offer was open to anyone interested, just ask to book a chat with the manager. Say you really like the company, you've heard there might be internships available in the future, and ask if it would be possible to apply for one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are aware that you are looking for another internship and would like to do it at company A if possible. Your friends should give you some indication that what they were told was to be kept in confidence.

Unless you feel there are negative feelings about the quality of your work, you should just be open and ask. The conversation may or may not get into whether or not you heard about the offer to your friends. My guess is whoever is in charge of interns would rather not have to go find/review new people if he can avoid it, so think of it as doing him a favor.